# Regex in java, group matching

Tags: java, regex

Hello how does java and regex group work. For ex. I want to match `any text 'something'`, the way I'd match this is `.+\s+'(.+)'{1}`, how can I replace any text 'something' with something?

Meaning replace matched string with 1st matched group.

Comment: Just FYI, your `{1}` is redundant -- `{1}` is implied on every atom.

Comment: please give a more specific example, e.g. exact input `ABCXYZ`, exact desired output `ABC123` or whatever.

Comment: For regular expressions, I always go check on the interwebz, on sites like  http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm

Comment: @cdhowie, the `{1}` is also only checking for a single `'` which is not likely what the OP intended.

Comment: @Brad: But the `'` *already* does exactly that.  `'` is equivalent to `'{1}`.  And `{1}` applied anywhere on a regex is meaningless and redundant, since it will never modify any regex's behavior.

Comment: @cdhowie, yes, you're right. I was simply stating that it was written in such a way that it was unlikely he was trying to enforce a single quote at the end (when he didn't at the beginning); he was more likely trying to enforce a single `'something'` which as you pointed out, is unnecessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to remove the single quotes, the following will work.

```
yourString.replaceAll("'([^']+)'", "$1");
```

That will search for 2 quotes with text in between.  And replace it with only the text.

```
System.out.println("any text 'something'".replaceAll("'([^']+)'", "$1"));
```

Prints `any text something`