# how to write regex for this expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I'am working on a regex str to match a expression: #acontent#url.
the expression start with "#a", and the "content" can be almost things, text,num or others, then end with "#" + url.

such as there is a text content: hello, man, this is something #ayou want#http://www.stackoverflow.com.

It will be match the string "#ayou want#http://www.stackoverflow.com",
I really don't konw how to write the regex.

Need some help please!

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430076/regex-in-java-group-matching?rq=1

Comment: "I really don't konw how to write the regex." Then you should learn http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer:

```
#a.+#((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+|(?:www\.|[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/\.\w\-_]*)?\??(?:[\-\+=&;%@\.\w_]*)#?(?:[\.\!\/\\\w]*))?)
```

This will match any character except line breaks in the content section, and should match any url.

NOTE: You will have to escape all backslashes in the given regex to represent it as a java String literal.

Sources for the url regex:

[What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

http://blog.mattheworiordan.com/post/13174566389/url-regular-expression-for-links-with-or-without

Fantastic resource for testing and building regexes:

http://www.regexr.com/